# What is the Best Way to Learn python-bitcoinlib?

Tags: python, python-bitcoinlib

I have tried to find tutorials everywhere, but can't find anything. Is there any step by step guide to use the library?

Answer (score 1):

1. Official documentations provides several examples.
   https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/tree/master/examples
2. project1 of Stanford cs251 guide you through P2PKH, atomic swap, etc.
   https://cs251.stanford.edu/